# How to create custom input slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question regarding to creating custom input slider the label inside field itself.

The output should be like in following screenshot:

[image: output]

I have done the input field part, but the label and white color part is missing.

```css
.slider-container .slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #b5b33c;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.slider-container .slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.content .slider-container .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #13bba4;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #54565a url("https://i.imgur.com/OuvOpHG.png") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #54565a url("https://i.imgur.com/OuvOpHG.png") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
            <input
              type="range"
              min="1"
              max="1000"
              value="50"
              class="slider"
              id="range"
            />
          </div>
```

Comment: The built in sliders are quite limited and rather browser-specific, I would definitely recommend building your own UI and using JS to "attach" it to a hidden slider behind the scenes if you want to do something like this.

Comment: @DBS yes I agree with that, I thought applying `position` to label to have same effect, but wanted to know if there is cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please check below demo link, where I have perform Javascript and CSS tweaks:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/0kz6xtns/290/

Please check and let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249954/discussion-between-kairav-thakar-and-nijat-mursali).

Comment: I adapted to your solution by adding custom label.

Comment: I got a problem, when I set default value to 100, the filled part is not changed initially

Comment: I have made value as 100 and it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/9dzx68v5/

Comment: It's weird because in my case it looks like this: https://imgur.com/J86QvoY

Comment: This is totally weird.

Comment: I have tested in my systems with different browsers and it's worked good

Comment: Can you please refresh the page and check it again?

Answer (score -1):

An onchange function can be created to get the slider value. This value can be get with the output tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-container">
        <input
          type="range"
          min="1"
          max="1000"
          value="50"
          class="slider"
          id="range"
          onchange="getRangeValue()"
        />
<output id="rangeOutput">50</output>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getRangeValue() {
document.getElementById("rangeOutput").value = document.getElementById("range").value
}
```

Comment: For suggestions you must use the comment section. Answer section is to post the answers.